# Qt Cannot append multiple file data to one

Tags: qt, file-copying

I have this program, I wanted to send the data of multiple files into a single file using a loop, but this doesn't seem to work properly.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char ch;
    QString str="test"+i+".txt";
    QString qString1 =str.toUtf8();
    QByteArray byteArray = qString1.toUtf8();

    const char* fname1 = byteArray.constData();
    if(QFile::exists("test0.txt"))
    fp1=fopen(fname1,"r");
    fp2=fopen("CheckoutReport.txt","a");
    do
    {
        ch=fgetc(fp1);
        fputc(ch,fp2);
    }
    while(ch!=EOF);
    fcloseall();
}
```

Comment: What is the exact issue that you are facing?

Comment: `QString qString1 =str.toUtf8()` doesn't make any sense. You converted `str` to `QByteArray` containing UTF-8 representation of the string, and immediately converted it back to QString using default constructor that uses Latin1 encoding. You should use `QByteArray byteArray = str.toLocal8Bit();` instead if you want to use this string in native functions. And you should use `QFile` instead of native functions.

Comment: It depends @PavelStrakhov : in Qt5, QString class stores 16-bit QChar corresponding to Unicode 4.0 (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#details), not Latin-1 which is the Qt4 default. That said, using toUtf8() and storing the result in a QString directly still doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Hint for novice programmers: always use `{}` block after any `if` statement (as well as with any loop), even if there is just one statement. It will save you a ton of headache.

Answer (score 1):

There's several problems:

1. You've got both C++ *and* Qt, use `QFile`, don't use naked C files!
2. `qString1` is a poor-man's copy of `str`, so what's the point of that?
3. Copying files character-by-character performs rather poorly.
4. You do not want to block your GUI while doing file operations, in general. They should be done in a separate thread.

Below is one example of how it could be done. I've strived to fully leverage what Qt has to offer, while keeping it QWidget-based. This is a self-contained, single-file example, simply add it as the lone file to a qt guy project in Qt Creator, then build and run. Remember that this code will open files in its current working directory!

The cost of using another thread in terms of code complexity is literally 6 lines. If you don't care for using a separate file-access thread and are OK with your UI being blocked by potentially slow files on the network etc., then the following 6 lines can be removed without any other changes in the code. That's the beauty of Qt.

```
QThread * m_thread;
w->moveToThread(m_thread);
m_thread(new QThread(this)),
m_thread->start();
m_thread->exit();
m_thread->wait();
```

Without the thread in place, you could also replace `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(w, "joinFiles");` with a simpler `w->joinFiles()`. The reason for using `invokeMethod` instead of a direct call is to invoke the slot in the thread where the object is running. `invokeMethod` will, behind the scenes, post a `QMetaCallEvent` to the worker object. This event will be picked up by the event loop running in the thread, and will result in a call to worker's `joinFiles` slot, *executed within the correct thread* - `worker->thread()`.

Note that I'm not deriving from `QThread`, and that only one thread is used for all file operations. This is perfectly adequate if your starting point is to have all file accesses done in the GUI thread. That way there are two threads: one that only does GUI, and another that only does serialized file accesses.

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>
#include <QThread>
#include <QApplication>

class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int fileIndex READ fileIndex WRITE setFileIndex)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString sourceFileName READ sourceFileName)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString targetFileName READ targetFileName WRITE setTargetFileName)
    int m_fileIndex;
    QString m_targetFileName;
public:
    Worker(int fileIndex, QString targetFileName, QObject * parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent), m_fileIndex(fileIndex), m_targetFileName(targetFileName) {}
    explicit Worker(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent), m_fileIndex(0) {}
    Q_SIGNAL void filesJoined(bool OK);
    Q_SLOT void joinFiles() {
        QFile src(sourceFileName());
        QFile dst(m_targetFileName);
        if (! src.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)
            || ! dst.open(QIODevice::Append))
        {
            emit filesJoined(false);
            return;
        }
        while (! src.atEnd()) {
            dst.write(src.read(16384));
        }
        emit filesJoined(true);
    }
    int fileIndex() const { return m_fileIndex; }
    void setFileIndex(int i) { m_fileIndex = i; }
    QString sourceFileName() const { return QString("test%1.txt").arg(m_fileIndex); }
    QString targetFileName() const { return m_targetFileName; }
    void setTargetFileName(const QString & n) { m_targetFileName = n; }
};

class Window : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread * m_thread;
    QSpinBox * m_index;
    QLineEdit * m_target;
    QPlainTextEdit * m_log;
    Q_SLOT void on_pushButton_clicked() {
        Worker * w = new Worker;
        w->setFileIndex(m_index->value());
        w->setTargetFileName(m_target->text());
        w->moveToThread(m_thread);
        connect(w, SIGNAL(filesJoined(bool)), SLOT(onJoined(bool)));
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(w, "joinFiles");
    }
    Q_SLOT void onJoined(bool ok) {
        const Worker * w = qobject_cast<const Worker*>(sender());
        m_log->appendPlainText(QString("%1 %2 to %3")
                               .arg(ok ? "Successfully joined" : "Couldn't join")
                               .arg(w->sourceFileName()).arg(w->targetFileName()));
        sender()->deleteLater();
    }
public:
    Window(QWidget * parent = 0) :
        QWidget(parent),
        m_thread(new QThread(this)),
        m_index(new QSpinBox),
        m_target(new QLineEdit),
        m_log(new QPlainTextEdit)
    {
        QFormLayout * layout = new QFormLayout(this);
        QPushButton * button = new QPushButton("Join Files");
        button->setObjectName("pushButton");
        layout->addRow("File Index", m_index);
        layout->addRow("Append to File Name", m_target);
        layout->addRow(button);
        layout->addRow(m_log);
        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this);
        m_thread->start();
        m_log->appendPlainText(QString("Current directory: %1").arg(QDir::currentPath()));
    }
    ~Window() {
        m_thread->exit();
        m_thread->wait();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Window w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: I wouldn't say `fgetc` and `fputc` perform especially poorly. They do internal buffering and performance might still be IO bound, just with increased CPU load.

Comment: @hyde: Sure, but in this case they are simply a demonstration of the asker having no clue how to do it otherwise. They are not used by design, they are used by happenstance. I want to de-reinforce the wrong way of doing it.